# Как найти класс по аннотации

Tags: java, xml, сериализация, аннотации

Делаю я сериалайзер-десериалайзер в xml. Есть у меня такой класс в каком-то пакете

```
@XMLAlias("organization")
public static class Organization{
 ...
}
```

Код аннотации:

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface XMLAlias {
    String value();
}
```

Соответсвенно в коде сериалайзера в том случае, если присутсвует аннотация, имя класса в итоговом xml документе заменяется на значение аннотации, в данном случае `<organization>`. Я не могу понять, как мне при десериализации найти в рантайме исходное имя класса(которое состоит из пакета + непосредственно имя класса),

Comment: Прошу прощения за оффтоп, но это у Вас какое-то тестовое задание или личный интерес? просто для этой цели вроде придуман JAXB

Comment: Вы хотите найти имя класса `test.Organization` по значению `organization` аннотации `XMLAlias`?

Comment: @Regent Вроде того) Надеюсь это возможно.

Comment: @Evgenb насколько я понимаю, для этого нужно просматривать все имеющиеся классы. Дабы не изобретать велосипед, можно воспользоваться [Google reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections). В этой библиотеке есть метод `getTypesAnnotatedWith`, возвращающий набор классов, имеющих данную аннотацию. Вот среди этого набора и нужно будет искать. Никогда этой библиотекой не пользовался, так что полноценного ответа дать не могу.

Comment: @Regent спасибо) ибо я даже не знал куда копать